# What's the best practice to implement a cross-controller animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, core-animation

```
,----------.      ,----------.
|          |      |       ⓘ |
|  ,----.  |      |          |
|  |LOGO|  | ===> |          |
|  `----'  |      |          |
|   VC1    |      |   VC2    |
`----------'      `----------'
```

I want to implement an animation like described in the draft above: when the UI transfers from VC1 (may be a welcome scene, with big logo at center) to VC2 (home scene, with an circled letter ***i*** at top right corner which is a ABOUT button), I want that logo to be gradually transformed to that small circled ***i***.

Because the logo view belongs to VC1 while the circled ***i*** belongs to VC2, I don't know how to animate them properly. May be transforming LOGO to circled ***i*** 's scale and position and then toggle their visibility is a good way( I'm not sure)

There are other animations of this kind and sometimes the simple  `transform --> toggle visibility` trick can't handle: Imagine that there is a textview ( may be a title ) needs to present in both `fromVC` and `toVC` of an animation, the other views (eg. background) needs a transform (eg. alpha-blending, blurring etc.). I did a hack that make textview belong to `fromVC` at the beginning and give it to `toVC` at the animation phase, this somehow works but looks a little bit dirty. Is there a better way (or best way) to achieve this ?

```
,-----------.      ,----------.
|           |      |  ,-----. |
|  ,-----.  |      |  |Title| |    The textview holding title may 
|  |Title|  | ===> |  `-----' |    translate during the animation
|  `-----'  |      |          |
|   VC1     |      |   VC2    |
`-----------'      `----------'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May be transforming LOGO to circled i 's scale and position and then
>   toggle their visibility is a good way( I'm not sure)

Yes. That is the way I would do it. Manage the animation within a single view controller, and instantly cut between controllers either before or after the animation.